# EmberJS - Assertion Failed: computed expects a function or an object as last argument

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Trying to use ember-models-table 3.x but facing an issue with "Assertion Failed: computed expects a function or an object as last argument."

ember-cli: 3.9.0

node: 10.16.1

Create a brand new ember project and updated the files below,

**routes/test.js**

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import {A} from '@ember/array';

export default Route.extend({
  setupController(controller) {
    controller.set('columns', A([
      { propertyName: 'index' },
      { propertyName: 'firstName' },
      { propertyName: 'lastName' },
      { propertyName: 'age' },
      { propertyName: 'city' }
    ]));
    controller.set('data', A({
      data: [
        { id: 1, type: 'movies', attributes: { name: 'Interstellar' } },
        { id: 2, type: 'movies', attributes: { name: 'Inception' } },
        { id: 3, type: 'movies', attributes: { name: 'Dunkirk' } },
      ]
    }));
  }
});
```

**templates/test.hbs**

```
<ModelsTable @data={{data}} @columns={{columns}} />
```

**router.js**

```
import EmberRouter from '@ember/routing/router';
import config from './config/environment';

const Router = EmberRouter.extend({
  location: config.locationType,
  rootURL: config.rootURL
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('test');
});

export default Router;
```

**Error**

```
index.js:163 Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: computed expects a function or an object as last argument.
    at assert (index.js:163)
    at new ComputedProperty (metal.js:2757)
    at computed (metal.js:3220)
    at Module.callback (models-table.js:192)
    at Module.exports (loader.js:106)
    at Module._reify (loader.js:143)
    at Module.reify (loader.js:130)
    at Module.exports (loader.js:104)
    at requireModule (loader.js:27)
    at Class._extractDefaultExport (index.js:426)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might have a slight typo in your Route  oh and Hey @moustacheman, thanks for your question

In your example you're trying to set `columns` and `data` as two arrays on your controller. The `columns` looks to be done right, but for data you're not passing an array into `A()` but instead you're passing an object that has a data parameter. I would update your example to:

```js
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import {A} from '@ember/array';

export default Route.extend({
  setupController(controller) {
    controller.set('columns', A([
      { propertyName: 'index' },
      { propertyName: 'firstName' },
      { propertyName: 'lastName' },
      { propertyName: 'age' },
      { propertyName: 'city' }
    ]));
    controller.set('data', A([
      { name: 'Interstellar' },
      { name: 'Inception' },
      { name: 'Dunkirk' },
    ]));
  }
});
```

Edit: I also removed the `id` and `type` structure that was part of the JSON:API spec because it's not relevant with the example that you're showing here. Also it's worth noting that you're setting columns `index`, `firstName` etc. but you only have the property `name` on the data. If you gave a more full example with a minimal reproduction I could make it work without any issue.

Comment: No, it is not working! Do you the data is required to be a JSON:API specification? Because ember-models-table@2 takes any array.

Comment: so when you're setting things directly as an array on the controller you don't need to be thinking in terms of JSON:API any more. JSON:API only applies in the responses to store queries, if you were doing something like `this.store.findAll('columns')` in your `model()` hook. And what do you mean by "It's not working"?